# Translating Links in Comments into User IDs

Tags: asana

When I get stories from the API with a type of "comment", several of them have links where Asana users/people are mentioned.

How to I translate these links into user ids?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't really a way to do that yet. The links in comments are processed through our Hypertext when displayed to users and contain a link to the user's "Assigned to Me", rather than some user profile.

We're thinking of ways to make the mapping easier on API consumers, but right now there isn't a solution planned.